# Orbeon "There was an error communicating with the datase"

Tags: orbeon

The saving the forms build in Orbeon we are encountering the error "There was an error communicating with the database"

Orbeon was installed in Windows Server 2012 with Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Maybe you should provide more information.

Comment: We can open the Orbeon (version orbeon-4.3.0.1.201308150213-CE) web site without problem. We can create the forms using the Form Builder but when we click the save button that is when we encounter the pop error saying "There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator."

Comment: Btw, the Orbeon is installed in a Windows Server 2012 with Apache Tomcat.

Comment: [Configure the location of the log file](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-Logging-configuration) and check if there is anything more telling in there after the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by @ebruchez in a comment, to debut this, I would also suggest you [setup logging](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-Logging-configuration) and check the `orbeon.log` for the underlying error. And of course, if the error on its own isn't enough for you to figure out what the problem is, feel free to update your question with additional information, or post another question.

Comment: For some reason, when we use Apache Tomcat version 7, saving of forms works.

Comment: OK good, I am glad you found a way to make this work (and if earlier you were using Tomcat 6, it sounds like a good idea anyway to upgrade to version 7).